# Ms Access query- FROM [Forms]![formname]!textbox value?

Tags: ms-access

I want to do a query that takes the table name from text box in a form and then put in "FROM table name".

Example: 
I have a form `"Form1"` with a text box, inside text box `"TextBox1"` the value is table1, table1 is exist.

I want to call the query

```
"SELECT [Forms]![Form1]![TextBox1].* FROM [Forms]![Form1]![TextBox1];"
```

But it shows `Syntax error` in FROM clause.
Please help.

Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

Easy syntax is

```
"SELECT [fields] FROM [tablename]"
```

So, if assumed there's not empty textbox1

```
"SELECT * FROM [" & [Forms]![Form1]![TextBox1] & "]"
```

Comment: `SELECT * FROM [" & [Forms]![Form1]![TextBox1] & "]"` would be more robust, wouldn't it?

Comment: @GordThompson : :) :) .. I'm walking on the syntax and i'm usually in VB .. so, you might be right ..